# Subtract Time from Datetime Field in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

This question seems obvious and easy but I am getting my head stretched out here. Problem is I have datetime field in model and I want to subtract time from another attribute.
here is my code I have tried so far.

```
@property
    def boarding_time(self):
        print('---------------------------')
        time = self.schedule.travel_date_time.time()
        print()
        time_added = self.schedule.bus_company_route.routeboardingpoint_set.get(
            point=self.boarding_point
        ).time_added
        time1 = timedelta(hours=time.hour, minutes=time.minute, seconds=time.second)
        time2 = timedelta(hours=time_added.hour, minutes=time_added.minute, seconds=time_added.second)
        return (time1-time2)
```

I am actually trying to find the time delay the vehicle reaches to certain destination. Suppose vehicle was supposed to move  at  8 am but the vehicle departed from bus park at 8:15 am and passenger waiting will have  15 min added to their location but I am getting error as

```
'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'isoformat'
```

Comment: you are trying to subtract one timedelta (`time2`) from another (`time1`) - that's why there is an error. But it's not clear from question, why are you doing that. Timedeltas supposed to add or subtract from datetime objects. So subtract `time2` right from `time`.

Comment: I am actually trying to find the time delay the vehicle reaches to certain destination. Suppose vehicle was supposed to move  at  8 am but the vehicle departed at 8:15 am and passenger waiting will have  15 min added to your location like that

Comment: then you may try to combine @edward-lu answer with my comment.

Supposed `time` is a datetime object and `time_added` as a time object (is it always on the same day?), you can take date part of `time`, then combine it with `time_added`, then subtract `time` from the result to get timedelta: `delta = datetime.combine(time.date(), time_added) - time`. This may work, but it will fail if `time_added` is on another day. If `time_added` is a datetime too, it gets much easier - just subtract `time` from `time_added`: `delta = time_added - time`.

Comment: i tried your approach as it is on same day so `return datetime.combine(self.schedule.travel_date_time.date(), time) - datetime.combine(self.schedule.travel_date_time.date(), time_added)
` but error is same

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this answers your question but you can try:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

datetime.combine(date.today(), exit) - datetime.combine(date.today(), enter)
```

combine builds a datetime, that can be subtracted. Your can google about it for more...
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: actually any date can by subtracted. Combine is for creating datetime from separate date and time objects.

Comment: got same error i tried this         `return datetime.combine(self.schedule.travel_date_time.date(), time) - datetime.combine(self.schedule.travel_date_time.date(), time_added)
`

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, the adjusted boarding time is derived from taking scheduled boarding time and adding to it the amount of time that lapsed between the scheduled departure time and the actual departure time from the previous destination.

Here is a simplified example that hopefully illustrates the key concepts to help you piece together a solution for your more complex problem:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

scheduled_boarding_time = datetime.fromisoformat("2021-01-12T10:00")
departure_delay_in_minutes = 15
adjusted_boarding_time = scheduled_boarding_time + timedelta(minutes=delay_in_minutes)
print(adjusted_boarding_time.isoformat())
```

```
2021-01-12T10:15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your question lies in the way you handle the time stamp format. You have your date time in `AM/PM` for this you have to format you date accordingly. Here is something what you can do instead of what you are doing right now

```
from datetime import datetime
time = '2021/1/13 8:15 am'    #your date format
time_added = '2021/1/13 8:45 am'    #your date format

format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M %p' #will format your date for further computation

time = datetime.strptime(time, format)

time
o/p
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 13, 8, 15)

time_added = datetime.strptime(time_added, format)

time_added
o/p
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 13, 8, 45)

time2 = time_added-time1 # this will give you time difference in seconds

divmod(time2.total_seconds(), 60)[0] #use this to get difference in minutes
o/p
30.0
```

This same you return in your function and it will solve your problem

Comment: i only have time in `time2` not whole date as it is of same date

Comment: so you want some hours or mins to get added in `time1` itself? example: `8am+30 mins = 8.30` am in `time2` and provide the format in which `time_added` is coming

Comment: and presumably the date added will also be a timestamp itself so it should work

Comment: `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime` got this

Comment: `strptime()` is required when you passing string as time as you see in my answer, the error you are getting because you already have datetime format that and you can directly apply `format()` instead of `strptime()`. Also you have to paste the output you are generating and error from that in question otherwise others can't debug because your trials are just with you